# Check if it has a related item before deleting in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp, relationship

I'd like to check to make sure that before a `Venue` is deleted, it doesn't have any `Events` tied to it.

```
Venue hasMany Event
Event belongsTo Venue
```

I believe I'd do this in a `beforeDelete` function in my Venue model - but - beyond that, I'm not sure how to check for Events... do I have to include access to the Event model somehow?  If it fails, is there a way to return a specific error message like validation allows?  Or... do I do this in the validation itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need. It will check for a count of events before deleting a venue, then if the count is greater than 0 it will return false, preventing the deletion. Else, it will delete if there are no events associated.

```
// using app/models/venue.php
// In the following example, do not let a venue delete if it still contains events.
// A call of $this->Venue->delete($id) from VenueController.php has set $this->id .
// Assuming 'Venue hasMany Event', we can access $this->Event in the model.
function beforeDelete(){
    $count = $this->Event->find("count", array("conditions" => array("venue_id" => $this->id)));
    if ($count == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you can do this:

**In your model add this method**

```
function hasEvents($venue_id){
    $count = $this->Event->find("count", array("conditions" => array("venue_id" => $venue_id)));
    if ($count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**In your controller**

```
if($this->Venue->hasEvents($venue_id)){
    //display error message that you cannot delete because venue has events
} else {
    $this->Venue->delete($venue_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.  Is there a way to set the error message instead of just "Venue was not deleted"?

Comment: In your controller, wrap your delete inside of a conditional, for example: 

if(!$this->Venue->delete($id)){
 $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, there was a problem deleting the venue');
 $this->redirect('action' => 'view', $id);
}

Comment: I'd like a specific error (if possible) similar to validation errors.  Is there a way to inform them the delete didn't happen because the Venue has Events tied to it?  Ie - in validation area, I can set 'message' => 'this is why it didn't save' ...etc

Comment: Well you're not calling a validation method. You are calling the delete method on your model.
The beforeDelete() method is called before $this->Venue->delete() call.
Therefore, if beforeDelete() returns false, $this->Venue->delete() will return false.
In your controller check if delete returned true (deleted) or false (not deleted).
Set the Session flash message or use $this->set('errorMessage', 'Your error here'); and in your view echo out $errorMessage where you want the error to display.

Comment: But won't ANY validation error also make $this->Venue-delete() return false?  So - how would I know what is causing it to return false?  I want to specify that's it's not been deleted due to an event, not due to any of the validation errors, or any other unknown-issue.  (sorry if this should be elementary - I greatly appreciate your help)

Comment: $this->delete doesn't call validation. You have to fake the validation in your controller. You can do that with the if statement in the previous comment.

Comment: So - the ONLY way it could not get deleted is if it fails my check?  What about unforseen errors?  (I assume since you haven't mentioned how I would do it, there's no way to set a specific error message for this?)

Comment: Can you explain the process that you are trying to accomplish?

Typically you would call $this->Venue->delete() from within your controller. The beforeDelete method is called anytime a $this->Venue->delete() call is made. If the beforeDelete method returns false, then nothing is deleted, if it returns true then the record is deleted. If beforeDelete returns true, $this->Venue->delete() will return true and you can check for true/false in your controller to display any errors in your view. I don't see what you're not getting. Can you explain your question better?

Comment: In my controller, I call $this->Venue->delete()   ... if for ANY reason, it doesn't delete, that will return false.  One of those reasons, is the code you just helped me with - if it finds out it has a related event, it will return false.  How do I know, in my controller, if the returned value of "false" came from YOUR check or any other check, or an error in the code or anything.  The false I'm specifying in your code is just one reason the delete might return false - I'd like to be able to tell the user that was the specific reason.

Comment: I use to accomplish the task: $_SESSION['Flash']['other_message'] = 'other message'; and in element/flash/error.php <?= @$_SESSION['Flash'['other_message']; ?>
    <?php unset($_SESSION['Flash']); ?> 10 years after =)

Answer (score 2):

use this behavior:

```
<?php
/**
 * Prevent deletion if child record found
 *
 * @author    Nik Chankov
 * @url    http://nik.chankov.net
 */
class HasChildrenBehavior extends ModelBehavior {
    /**
     * Empty Setup Function
    */
    function setup(&$model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    /**
     * Run the check and cancel the deletion if child is found
     * @access public
     */
    function beforeDelete(){
        if(isset($this->model->hasMany)){
            foreach($this->model->hasMany as $key=>$value){
                $childRecords = $this->model->{$key}->find('count', array('conditions'=>array($value['foreignKey']=>$this->model->id)));
                if($childRecords > 0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        //Checking habtm relation as well, thanks to Zoltan
        if(isset($this->model->hasAndBelongsToMany)){
            foreach($this->model->hasAndBelongsToMany as $key=>$value){
                $childRecords = $this->model->{$key}->find('count', array('conditions'=>array($value['foreignKey']=>$this->model->id)));
                if($childRecords > 0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

SOURCE: http://nik.chankov.net/2007/10/23/check-for-existing-childs-behaviour/

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to CakePHP, so please take this answer with a grain of salt.

I believe since Venue has a relationship to Event you can access it without any modifications with something like:

$this->Event ...

from the Venue Model or Controller.

You should then me able to use a query to find any Event with that venue.

Comment: Sounds good, but - any chance you could supply a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

for use cakephp 3.5.1 try this..

in Products model

Products belongsTo Categories

in Categories controller

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    if($this->checkassociated($id) > 0){
        $this->Flash->error(__('this category could not be deleted.'));
    }else{
        $category = $this->Categories->get($id);
        if ($this->Categories->delete($category)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('this category has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('this category could not be deleted.'));
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}

public function checkassociated($category_id){
    $itemsTable = TableRegistry::get('Products');
    $itemdata = $itemsTable->find('all')
        ->where(['Products.category_id'=>$category_id]);
    $number = $itemdata->count();
    return $number;
}
```